# s3cmd add lifecycle rule for object in bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am using s3smd package in ubuntu for uploading files on aws.
Now i want to add lifecycle rule for different objects inside bucket. 
I can see the commands  from http://s3tools.org/usage

According to s3cmd git page(https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/pull/295) 
I am using like this

```
s3cmd put --recursive  ${TMP_PATH}${FILENAME}${DATESTAMP}.tar.gz s3://${S3BUCKET}/${S3PATH}day/
s3cmd expire s3://${S3BUCKET} --expiry-days=365 --expiry-prefix=log/
```

but keep getting error

```
Usage: s3cmd [options] COMMAND [parameters]

s3cmd: error: no such option: --expiry-days
```

i am unable to find working example for how to add expiry date/lifecycle rule for a object in bucket. 
Let me know what i am doing wrong 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question, but it appears on google, so worth answering.

Ubuntu (14.04) ships with an old version of `s3cmd`. You can check this by running

```
s3cmd --version
```

The best thing to do is to install it with pip, the python package manager.

```
sudo apt-get remove s3cmd && sudo apt-get install python-pip && pip install s3cmd
```

You may need to log out, then back in to allow your path to s3cmd to update. But after that if you

```
s3cmd --version
```

You should get a much later version. Your expire flag should now work fine.